# zsh: segmentation fault While I'm running opencv in vs code,I can't find the answer

Tags: python, opencv

```
    import cv2 
import numpy as np

def empty(v):
    pass

img = cv2.imread('ttt.jpeg')
img = cv2.resize(img,(0,0),fx=0.9,fy=0.9)

cv2.namedWindow('Trackbar')
cv2.resizeWindow('Trackbar',640,320)

cv2.createTrackbar('Hue Min','Trackbar',0,179,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar('Hue Max','Trackbar',179,179,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar('Sat Min','Trackbar',0,255,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar('Sat Max','Trackbar',255,255,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar('Val Min','Trackbar',0,255,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar('Val Max','Trackbar',255,255,empty)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
while True:
    h_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Ｈue Min','Trackbar')
    h_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Ｈue Max','Trackbar')
    s_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Sat Min','Trackbar')
    s_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Sat Max','Trackbar')
    v_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Val Min','Trackbar')
    v_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Val Max','Trackbar')
    print(h_min,h_max,s_min,s_max,v_min,v_max)
    
    lower = np.array([h_min,s_min,v_min])
    upper = np.array([h_max,s_max,v_max])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower,upper)
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    cv2.imshow('hsv',hsv)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Device:macbook air m1

When I run the code,

```
zsh: segmentation fault  /Users/mike/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

showed up.

Where the problem is? I've searched on the Internet for a long time, but still can't find a useful method thanks!

Comment: Does the interpreter work if you run it without a script path to get the REPL?

Comment: Change this cv2.imshow('img',img) to cv2.imshow('Trackbar', img)

Comment: If none of the above suggestions work, could you try and comment out lines from the bottom, until you find the point where the error disappears? That would at least point to the offending line & function.

Comment: Segmentation fault means the python binary in anaconda is corrupt or missing some libraries, most likely you have the x86 mac binaries not the arm64 needed for m1. please try reinstalling anaconda.

Comment: is this FULL error message? Do you have problem when you run other script? Do you have problem when you run `python` without script?

Comment: Actually,the same file on windows is no problem.However,on m1 macbook ,zsh: segmentation fault  /Users/mike/opt/anaconda3/bin/python showed up